# Need help with Guava Tree Insect

Tags: pests

This bug seems attached to my guava tree under leaf. I only found one.  And there are holes in some leaves.
The affected leaves are clustered together. I'm in Hawaii at 1300 windy feet.

[image: Black and yellow striped beetle]